# How to do headless protractor/jasmine testing?

Tags: coffeescript, jasmine, protractor

I have got protractor installed with jasmine/coffeescripts with chromedriver.

I am running my tests and chrome starts and it runs everything. That's fine.

But, if i run this from remote (ssh) headless, it says

```
using ChromeDriver directly...
Spec started
A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.
The last active task was:
WebDriver.createSession()
    at <anonymous>
    at <anonymous>
    at <anonymous>
    at <anonymous>

  Going to the Connect pages and launch at dashboard
    ✗ Should login as admin and launch Location view (30 secs)
      - timeout: timed out after 30000 msec waiting for spec to complete
```

How can i run these tests in headless mode?

Thanks,
R

Comment: It looks to me like they are trying to run, but something isn't right. Make sure that the remote login can bring up the page you are trying to load.

Comment: Shouldn't be using xvfb or phantomjs or something in order to make it work headless?

Comment: Using phantom isn't recommended for Protractor due to rendering issues. Personally, I use the free VirtualBox VMs from Microsoft Edge (http://dev.modern.ie/tools/vms/windows/) and run those headless and everything works like a champ. You can install other browsers on them too. Makes for a good testing base.

Comment: I want to use chrome not IE. I want to use chrome and protractor to test headless. i heard xvfb can be used in order to achieve this. Any insights on how i can make it working?

Comment: What part of "You can install other browsers on them too." did you not understand? I test with IE, Chrome, and Firefox on one machine, simultaneously, and it all works fine. However, you seem intent on using xvfb and @cvakiitho has presented a working answer. Also, limiting your testing to one browser is not wise, but hey, it's your project.

Answer (score 2):

Only way I know about is xvfb, but it is a pain to get working imho. 
fortunately somebody already did that for us:

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium
So basically you only need to install docker

`curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh`

then start docker deamon

`sudo service docker start`

and then start hub + browser, or standalone browser:

```
docker run -d --name selenium-hub -p 4444:4444 selenium/hub:2.47.1
docker run -d --name chrome1 --link selenium-hub:hub selenium/node-chrome:2.46.0
docker run -d --name chrome2 --link selenium-hub:hub selenium/node-chrome:2.46.0
docker run -d --name firefox1 --link selenium-hub:hub selenium/node-firefox:2.46.0
```

or standalone:

```
docker run -d -p 4444:4444 selenium/standalone-chrome-debug:2.47.1
```

Also remember to kill docker containers, after tests, as they are not made to survive long :)

```
docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q --filter 'name=chrome')
docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q --filter 'name=firefox')
docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q --filter 'name=selenium-hub')
```

And I almost forgot, inside your ptor config, or grunt args, or cli arg : `seleniumAddress: 'http://<serverWithHubAddress>:4444/wd/hub',`

Comment: While you have presented a valid answer, I disagree with your assertion that this is the "only" way to do it. There are quite a few other ways.